# Extend [edit] link markup to allow arbitrary text

Tags: feature-request

I'm a great believer in reminding new users that they should [edit](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/3719/edit) their question to include updates rather than losing them amongst comments. What I find, though, is that the single word [edit](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/3719/edit) is sometimes not as useful or visible as a [link to the edit button with some descriptive text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/3719/edit).

I have found that it's not possible to use arbitrary text without unrolling the convenient shortcut [edit], and I was hoping that it would be a reasonable request to have [edit] work with [any relevant text](edit).

I could then write *please [edit your question](edit)* rather than *please [edit your question](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/3719/edit)*

Comment: Yes, that would indeed be useful. On a similar note, I [asked for](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268290/203101) a `[formatting]` magic link on the main meta and someone was nice enough to answer it with a [userscript](http://stackapps.com/q/6650/17253) that lets you set arbitrary magic links. You might want to give it a try.

Comment: @terdon I'd love to, thank you. How do I install it (I've read the instructions on where to get the code. But what then)?

Comment: [This answer](http://superuser.com/a/252049/151431) explains it quite well for a variety of browsers. I use the GUI (cinnamon) and a file manager to drag it onto my chrome's extension page, so just like Windows (!). Firefox requires the greasemonkey addon.